# Indefinite integration of multiplication of two Bessel function

Tags: integration, integral-transforms, bessel-functions

I am trying to calculate this integral. I know it has an analytic expression when $a = 0$. But, is there any analytic expression for this case?

$$\int_{a}^{\infty}J_2(bx)J_1(cx)\,dx$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following may be helpful: For $a=0$ we have a known formula; writing $\int_0^\infty-\int_0^a$ we get a formula for your case; might be possible because $\int_0^a J_\mu(x)J_{\mu+1}(x)dx = \sum_{k \ge 0} J_{\mu+k+1}(a)^2$, though haven't given it more thought.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "analytic expression". The integral that you wrote is an analytic expression (in my vocabulary).

Comment: I mean analytic solution. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "analytic solution". We are talking about an integral (not an equation), which is analytic (complex differentiable) in $a$. The word "solution" makes no sense in this context.

Comment: OK, let me explain it in this way. Can you solve the integral? Find any F(x) in an explicit way, that you may put it on the right side.

Comment: An integral cannot be "solved". Also, the expression you wrote is completely explicit.

Comment: So we are going to argue about the terminology I use? Yes, you probably know much more than me. So please, if you can help, just help to integrate this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12696/discussion-between-artalexan-and-gh-from-mo)

Comment: Isn't it the Hankel transform of the Bessel function itself? Then this should give rise to so called Zernike polynomials. Have a look at formula (7) in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.0667.pdf

Comment: It is the Hankel transform when $a = 0$, as I know.

Answer (score 1):

For the case $b=c$ ...
$$
\int \!{{\rm J}_2\left(bx\right)}{{\rm J}_1\left(bx\right)}{dx}=
\frac{1}{2b}-{\frac { \left( {{\rm J}_0\left(bx\right)} \right) 
^{2}}{2b}}-{\frac { \left( {{\rm J}_1\left(bx\right)} \right) ^{2}}{b
}}
$$
(I used Maple.)

Comment: unfortunately in my case $b\neq c$

Answer (score 0):

Using formula (18.17) at [this link here](http://books.google.com/books?id=qy1GNv2ovHQC&lpg=PA59&dq=integral%20product%20bessel%20functions&pg=PA59#v=onepage&q=integral%20product%20bessel%20functions&f=false), you can get a power-series for $J_2(bx)J_1(cx)$, which you can simplify and integrate term-by-term to obtain a "closed-form" expression for your integral. Maple or Mathematica might be able to simplify that even further.

Alternatively, you can look the book *Integrals of Bessel Functions* by Y. L. Luke, McGraw Hill. 1962.